# Is there a way to do a conditional join in R with a defined set of rules?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I've created a sample `tbl_df`.  Is there a way to do a join in `dplyr` (preferred) or create a function with a defined set of rules to allow me to do a join to match NA's?

For example, in the below example I want to join based on `name`, `comic_type`, and `comic_year`.  For `df2`, I'd like to set a hierarchy for matching purposes to `left_join` to `df1`. The `join` `df` shows a sample of the `NA` that result from a traditional `left_join`

Example using codes in the `comic_type` column.  I'm basically looking to fix the `NA` in the sample `df` I created using a `left_join` titled `join`

1. **FF:** If FF from `join` `is.na`, first look to match FF to FO, and if there is no match, then to TA
2. **AD**: join to AC, then DO, then FF

The `df` and codes in my example are made up out of thin air, but hopefully this example serves the purpose.  I'm looking to do a conditional join using a set of parameters that have a hierarchy attached to them.  The `df` I plan on doing this on has a ton more rows and columns.

Example:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


superheroes <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~alignment, ~gender, ~publisher, ~comic_type, ~comic_year,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "FF",       2015L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "AA",       2015L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "AD",       2020L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "FF",       2018L,
  "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "BC",       2015L,
  "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "FF",       2015L,
  "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "AA",       2020L,
  "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "AD",       2018L
)


scores <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~comic_type, ~comic_year, ~score,
  "Magneto",        "FO",       2015L,     7L,
  "Magneto",        "AA",       2015L,     9L,
  "Magneto",        "AC",       2020L,     9L,
  "Magneto",        "FF",       2018L,     5L,
  "Batman",        "BC",       2015L,     2L,
  "Batman",        "FF",       2015L,     9L,
  "Batman",        "AA",       2020L,     5L,
  "Batman",        "FF",       2018L,     5L
)

join <- left_join(superheroes, scores)
#> Joining, by = c("name", "comic_type", "comic_year")

join
#> # A tibble: 8 x 7
#>   name    alignment gender publisher comic_type comic_year score
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     <chr>           <int> <int>
#> 1 Magneto bad       male   Marvel    FF               2015    NA
#> 2 Magneto bad       male   Marvel    AA               2015     9
#> 3 Magneto bad       male   Marvel    AD               2020    NA
#> 4 Magneto bad       male   Marvel    FF               2018     5
#> 5 Batman  good      male   DC        BC               2015     2
#> 6 Batman  good      male   DC        FF               2015     9
#> 7 Batman  good      male   DC        AA               2020     5
#> 8 Batman  good      male   DC        AD               2018    NA

expected_output <- 
tibble::tribble(
      ~name, ~alignment, ~gender, ~publisher, ~comic_type, ~comic_year, ~score,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "FF",       2015L,     7L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "AA",       2015L,     9L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "AD",       2020L,     9L,
  "Magneto",      "bad",  "male",   "Marvel",        "FF",       2018L,     5L,
   "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "BC",       2015L,     2L,
   "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "FF",       2015L,     9L,
   "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "AA",       2020L,     5L,
   "Batman",     "good",  "male",       "DC",        "AD",       2018L,     5L
  )
```

So in the example above, the expected output basically uses the rules to replace the `NA` in `join` that are a result of a `left_join`.  `FF` joins to the `comic_type` `FO` based on the rules above and joins the `score`, and the same for `NA` for `AD` in join.  `AD` joins to `FF` based on the 2nd rule above.

Comment: Can you please add your expected output? I'm not clear on how your rules will play out.

Comment: Also, as you have condition with `NA`, it may be better to include those cases as well

Comment: Added expected output, and hopefully clarified further.  In addition, if I get the hierarchy to work properly there should no longer be any NA when we join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `data.table` approach is more manual than I would like. Not my proudest code, but it works (on the sample data at least).
See comments in code for explanation.

```
library( data.table )
#make it data.table format
setDT( superheroes ); setDT( scores )

#create id to use .EACHI on, set is as a key (will be deleted at the end)
superheroes[, id := .I ]
setkey( superheroes, id )
#loop over rows (each i = .EACHI on the bottom) of superheroes
superheroes[ superheroes, score := { 
  #create a dynamic subset of the scores-data.table,
  #  based on the row of superheroes we a currently at
  temp = scores[ name == i.name & comic_year == i.comic_year, ]
  #sort temp if the current superheroes$comic_type == FF
  if (i.comic_type == "FF") temp <- temp[ order( factor( comic_type, levels = c("FF", "FO", "TA") ) ), ]
  #idem for when is AD
  if (i.comic_type == "AD") temp <- temp[ order( factor( comic_type, levels = c("AD", "AC", "DO", "FF") ) ), ]
  #if not FF or AD, then subset by comic_type
  if (!i.comic_type %in% c("FF", "AD")) temp <- temp[ comic_type == i.comic_type, ]
  #take the first row score from temp and return 
  list( temp$score[1] )
  }, by = .EACHI ][, id := NULL ][]  #id := NULL drops the temporary id column, [] passes output to console

#       name alignment gender publisher comic_type comic_year score
# 1: Magneto       bad   male    Marvel         FF       2015     7
# 2: Magneto       bad   male    Marvel         AA       2015     9
# 3: Magneto       bad   male    Marvel         AD       2020     9
# 4: Magneto       bad   male    Marvel         FF       2018     5
# 5:  Batman      good   male        DC         BC       2015     2
# 6:  Batman      good   male        DC         FF       2015     9
# 7:  Batman      good   male        DC         AA       2020     5
# 8:  Batman      good   male        DC         AD       2018     5
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This appears to work (I did it on a subset of my data).  A few questions: How would I change this code into a function so that I can assign it to a different df name if I wanted?  Can you add an alternate option, or what would the code be if I wanted to join an additional column in scores (the second df) that doesn't reside in the first df?

Comment: What would an alternate option look like that had an additional criteria based on a column that resides in both df meeting a criteria like superheroes$records <= 10 from scores$records?